# How to use position fixed in flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout with two columns.

The left column be fixed, while the right is scrollable.

How can you do that?

Take a look at the following code:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#left div {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
#right {
  flex-grow: 5;
  background: red;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id ="left">
    <div>
      ABC
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id ="right">
  DEF
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spfroavm/4/)

Comment: How is your fiddle not exactly what you're describing?

Comment: @Dan Farrell - the width of the fixed div is not the parents width. added some details to the code.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. You will have to set a width for the sidebar, or calculate it dynamically with JavaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you want make the right scroll and the left be fixed. That can be done without the use of fixed position.

I would also personally recommend to not use fixed position, unless it is absolutely necessary, as it can have some unwanted behavior on mobile device, and you kind of loose the benefit non positioned solutions like `flexbox` offer.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
#left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: blue;
}
#right {
  flex-grow: 5;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#right div {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id ="left">
      ABC
  </div>
  <div class="child" id ="right">
    <div>
      DEF
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

here you go

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
#left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightgray;
}
#right {
  flex-grow: 5;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.scroll {
  height: 300vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="left">
    <div>
      ABC
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="right">
    <div class="scroll">
      DEF
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in the comments:

> the width of the fixed div is not the parents width.

When you add `position: fixed` to an element, you remove it from the normal flow of the document and position it *relative to the viewport*.

The fixed element has no reason to recognize the parent's width in the HTML structure.

You may be able to achieve what you want by making the entire layout fixed ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410062/3597276)). Otherwise, you'll need a JavaScript alternative.